# Object does not contain a definition for 'Select'

Tags: c#, vsto

I am running this code in a separate project and it works no issue, but for some reason in this project it throws a compile error. What is incorrect with this statement:

```
private static Excel.Application docExcel;
docExcel.Sheets[wsCount + 1].Select();
```

Error:

> Object does not contain a definition for 'Select'

Image of installed references:

[image]

Comment: Do you have all required references (specifically the interop assemblies) in the new project?

Comment: I just added an image of my installed references.  Shouldn't the Interop.Excel cover this?

Comment: It should, but some extension methods are contained in other assemblies (for example if that was LINQs Select function, you would need a reference and using for System.Linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to call the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.select%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method on a `Worksheet` and not the Linq `Select` method or some other extension method.

The [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.item.aspx) for the `Sheets` collection returns an `object` since it can contain many different types of wheets (worksheets, charts, etc.) and there's not a common base type between those classes.

If you know that you are selecting a worksheet, use the `Worksheets` property instead and explicitly cast it:

```
private static Excel.Application docExcel;
((Excel.Worksheets)docExcel.Worksheets[wsCount + 1]).Select();
```

Comment: same issue as above with this code.

Comment: OK So you still have to explicitly cast - but it will be safer to use `Worksheets` since it can only return `Worksheet` objects.